# Joomla, add position into file

Tags: php, html, joomla, joomla-template, joomla-module

I want to connect my Joomla module with position.

How can I create this position (user position)? Where is this file in the template?

Answer (score 0):

In general each template includes some positions, first check the positions available
 in your template.

Go to **System** > **Global Configuration** > **Templates**
From here enable the option **Preview Module Positions**.

Now if you go to **Extensions** > **Templates**
 You can click in the little eye icon or add in your url something like:

- yoursite.com/**?tp=1**

Now you can go to **Extensions** > **Modules** > **Your Module**, here select the position 
of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to create new positions (not defined in your current template) you have to edit `/templates/template_name/index.php` and add a jdoc:include statement where you need:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="new-position" style="xhtml" />
```

Then edit `/templates/template_name/templateDetails.xml` adding the position:

```
<positions>
    ...
    <position>new-position</position>
    ...
</positions>
```

In some templates, positions could not be in index.php, in that case search for other files that defines the template layout (always in `/template/template_name/` folder or subdirectories).

Also consider to ask **Joomla related questions** on [joomla.stackexchange.com](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/) to get better answers!